# Get current page URL without query parameters - Razor Html helper?

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2013

Is there a method in Razor that returns the current pages URL without the query parameters.

I need to shove it into an HTML helper method I have created as a string.

`@Url` does not seem to work and if I do `.ToString()` I just get the namespace LOLLL

**Razor use:**

```
<th width="100%" @Html.SortTableClickEvent(@Url.ToString(), "Name")>
```

**Html helper:**

```
    public static MvcHtmlString SortTableClickEvent(this HtmlHelper html, string url, string column)
    {
        StringBuilder sortingPropertiesObject = new StringBuilder();
        sortingPropertiesObject.Append("var properties = new James.prototype.Table.SortingProperties();");
        sortingPropertiesObject.Append("properties.url = \"" + url + "\"");
        sortingPropertiesObject.Append("properties.colName = \"" + column + "\"");

        string clickEvent = "onclick = James.Table.SortByColumn(properties, this);";

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sortingPropertiesObject + clickEvent);
    }
```

**What gets output to my html:**

```
<th width="100%" onclick='James.Table.SortByColumn("Name",' this);="" properties.colname="Name" james.prototype.table.sortingproperties();properties.url="System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper" properties="new" var="">
            Name
        </th>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `Request.Url.GetLeftPart` method for that. If your URL is say

```
http://the-site.com/controller/action?param=1
```

executing `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)` should give

```
http://the-site.com/controller/action
```

In code that might look like this:

```
<th width="100%" @Html.SortTableClickEvent(@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path), "Name")>
```

Comment: @Request.Path seems to do the job too!

Comment: @JamesT, well, it depends on what your needs. If you need full path, with scheme and domain parts, then `GetLeftPart` is to be used. If `/controller/action` part is enough for you  - then `Request.Path` will do indeed.

Answer (score 9):

Without querystring:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)
```

With querystring

```
Request.Url.PathAndQuery
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used which also works to get rid of ANYTHING the right of the action.

```
 public static string GetParameterlessPath(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        return GetParameterlessPath(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName,
            VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
    }

    public static string GetParameterlessPath(string action, string relativeUrl)
    {
        return  relativeUrl.Contains(action) 
             ? relativeUrl.Substring(0, relativeUrl.LastIndexOf(action))+action 
             : relativeUrl;
    }
```

This is obviously a static method, but I put it in my ActionFilter hence where I am getting the ActionExecutingContext. If you have the action and the relativeUrl (or any url for that matter) that bottom method should work for you.

Comment: And a version for JS:

function GetParameterlessPath(action, relativeUrl)
        {
            if (relativeUrl.indexOf(action) == -1)
                return relativeUrl;

            return relativeUrl.substring(0, relativeUrl.lastIndexOf(action)) + action;
        }