# URL Redirect to Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a method that will apply to 2 different views "/DogProfile" and "/DogProfile/Profile" I want to call this method and then have it return to the current page, as it does now for "DogProfile". However, I am having trouble identifying how to create a variable that would store the url of the page I am operating from. i.e. now if I were on the Profile view and run the page I am redirected to the "/DogProfile" page instead of back to the "DogProfile/Profile" page.

Dog Profile Controller:

```
  public IActionResult CheckOut(string activity, int dogID)
    {
        var status = context.Dogs.Find(dogID);
        status.CheckedOut = true;
        status.Activity = activity;
        status.TimeCheckOut = DateTime.Now;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("/dogprofile");
    }
```

Profile view:

```
    @model WebApplication2.Models.Dog;
<h1>@Model.DogName</h1>
<img src="@Model.ImageSource" class="dogProfile"><img />

<br />
<br /> 

@if (Model.Description != null)
{
    <h2>Dog Special Requirements:</h2>
    <p>@Model.Description</p>
}

<form asp-controller="DogProfile" asp-action="CheckOut" method="post">
    <select name="activity" id="activity">
        <option value="walk">Walk</option>
        <option value="furlough">Furlough</option>
        <option value="bathe">Bathe</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Check Out" />
    <input type="hidden" name="dogID" value="@Model.Id" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current page URL without query parameters - Razor Html helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948908/get-current-page-url-without-query-parameters-razor-html-helper)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit via the Profile page and return to the current  `"DogProfile/Profile"` page instead of the `"/DogProfile"` page, you can try the following code.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CheckOut(string activity, int dogID)
    {
        var status = _context.Dogs.Find(dogID);
        status.CheckedOut = true;
        status.Activity = activity;
        status.TimeCheckOut = DateTime.Now;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("/dogprofile/profile" + "/" + dogID);
    }
```

Comment: If it does'nt work,you can provide your profile's get method.

Comment: I am wanting it to return both options depending on what page I view it on so I need some sort of variable that stores that